# RabbitMQ: Dispatcher for messages that contain many tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to distribute a message via RabbitMQ that contains many tasks:

```
Producer --> RabbitMQ Exchange --> 10 Consumers
```

E.g.:
The User sends a message to the exchange that contains 1000 tasks. The exchange needs to distribute the tasks evenly to the consumers with the shortest queue.

Since the producer has no knowledge of the queuing mechanisms used within RabbitMQ, the exchange needs some custom logic for splitting the order into tasks and distributing them to consumer queues.

How is this done? (I am using Python/Pika on both the producers and consumers.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a lot simpler if you used a single queue, and had multiple consumers attached to that queue and leveraged [Consumer Prefetch (QoS)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html). This way you could send a 1000 messages to that queue, and have the available consumers pick up the messages.

```
Producer --> RabbitMQ Exchange --> RabbitMQ Queue --> 10 Consumers
```

Consumer Prefetch (QoS) basically just means that you can set the number of messages that the consumer will pre-fetch. As an example, if you set this to 1, pika would only fetch and process one message at a time, giving other consumers a chance of consuming and processing the other 999 messages.

Comment: Good idea for even distribution, but the producer would still have to send 1000 messages, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to distribute a single message containing 1000 tasks,  and have 10 different consumers process parts of that message? I would probably just split that message into 10 messages, and go with the above. That way you will only be sending 10, not 1000 messages.

Comment: Exactly! Unfortunately 1000 tasks was only an example - in practice the number will vary up to ~100.000 or more. The overhead for packaging them each into a message would just be too much. Not to mention that tracking them all for completion would be hairy.

Comment: I unfortunately don't think this is something you can solve with RabbitMQ. It feels like you are trying to do something that is outside of AMQP's responsibilities.